# Mongoose: insert one collection depenting on an other with promises

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, promise

I need to insert records in two collections. The second collection stores the ID of records of the first collection. It is a 1:m (fisrt:second) situation. The trigger is the second collection:

1. If a record for the second collection needs to be stored
2. check if there is already a fitting record in the first collection
3. if not: then save one in the first collection
4. store the second collection
5. save the id of the record of the first collection in the second collection

The following example seems to fullfill these steps. But I have the promises only half way. 
**How can this be done in a better "promised" way?**

```
saveObjects(name: String, objects: Array<IObject>){

        var promise = FirstModel.findOne({Name : name}).exec();
        promise.then(function(res1){
            if (!res1){
                var la = new FirstModel();
                la.Name = name;
                la.save(function(err){
                    if (err) throw err;
                })
            }
        }).error(function(err){
            throw err;
        })

        objects.forEach(function(obj) {
            FirstModel.findOne({Name : name},'_id',function(err, res2){
                if (err) throw err;

                var vo = new SecondModel();
                vo.Name = name;
                vo.FistID = res2._id;

                vo.save(function(err){
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm gona assume here that you're using bluebird or another promise equivalent set up.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
saveObjects(name: String, objects: Array < IObject > ) {

    // Get the first model
    return FirstModel
        .findOne({
            Name: name
        })
        .exec()
        .then(function (res1) {
            if (!res1) {
                var la = new FirstModel();
                la.Name = name;
                return la.save() // We return the save operation on the model, save() returns a promise
            }

            // We just return the model normally so it passes down the chain.
            return res1;
        })
        .then(function (res1) {
            // Here we use Promise.all() method on bluebird which accepts an Array
            // of promises, we create a promise from the objects array by using Array.map() which
            // goes through every object in the array and creates a new array. 
            return Promise
                .all(objects.map(function (obj) {
                    // We go through each object in objects and create a new 
                    // model and return the save() method of each model, this
                    // creates a array of promises which are resolved when each
                    // all model has been saved.
                    var vo = new SecondModel();
                    vo.Name = name;
                    vo.FistID = res1._id;

                    return vo.save();
                }));
        })
        .then(function (models) {
            // here we have all the models we just saved in an array called models,
            // do what you want with it.
        })
        .error(function (err) {
            throw err;
        })
}
```

For more info see documentation on [Array.map() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Promise.all() here](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html)

Comment: But the reference `vo.FistID = res1._id;`to the FirstModel, throws anerror in the above example since res1._id  is not in the scope  in the .then part. This is why I did a further read on FirstModel at this place. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: res1 is defined in the second then() so it should work fine. We pass res1 from the first then() to the second. If you are getting an error paste it here so i can see what it is. If you copy/pasted directly you should know that I just fixed a minor syntax error so you should try again.

Comment: The error I get is`error TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type '{}'.` This seems to be for me that res1 is not know in the second part.

Comment: Looks like a typescript error to me, I have little experience with typescript but my guess is that you need a typescript definition for FirstModel in the function, something like .then(function(res1: FirstModel) { ... })

Comment: What I added to your code was pure javascript so you might need to modifyit a bit for it to work properly with typescript. Aside from that, this is perfectly valid javascript code for what you are trying to achieve unless you have defined the id on the FirstModel as something other than _id.

Comment: thanks a lot. Yes it seems to be a TS issues. Though I could not  solve it by adding a type. I did an extra read down the chain.. But in a simple js environment I have just copied your code and I call commit that it works - so thanks again.